# why i should use private key on my pc to ssh my server?

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption

i just learned that in key based Authentication the sender should have the private key and the receiver should have public key and it's one way encryption the private decrypt the public then how come when i ssh to my server i have the private key on pc and the public key is on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User who want to connect to remote server should have private key on his side.
Remote server should have public key, paired with private key to allow user connect.

If you want to connect from remote server to your pc, you should put private key on remote server and public to your pc.

So, to have two-ways configured key-based authentication, you should have private and public key on both machines.

Comment: More precisely, you should probably use *separate* pairs of keys in each direction. That way, if the private key for connecting from the server to the PC is compromised, you don't have to replace the private key for connecting *to* the server.

Comment: let's assume i connect from pc to server that means that all traffic comming from the server will be encrypted with puplic key then what about the the traffic send from my pc to server how it will be encrypted

Comment: No, it doesn't work like this.
async encryption is too heavy to encrypt the whole traffic, so it is used only to safe exchange secrets for establishing SSH session and for authorization.
So your keys are used ONLY for authorization.